# Cocoapods the document ".xcworkspace" could not be opened

Tags: cocoapods, xcode-workspace

I tried to install some Pods into my Project.

I kept getting the error message:

```
 The document "S&J.xcworkspace" could not be opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my Project name contained the `&`.  I created a new project with a different name (without the `&`) and everything worked fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. This actually helped, spend several hours figuring out why my .xcworkspace wasn't opening, only to read your post and found that was making the same mistake of having & in my file name... Changed the name and boom, like magic, app running like a champ.. :)

Comment: This should be a comment